# How to make a light turn off at a certain time of day

Tags: time, unity-game-engine, unityscript, lighting

I'm currently making an exploration game and using a dynamic time of day changer for day and night. I wanted to know how to turn off the player's flashlight at noon of the day. The script for the TOD setting:

```
var slider: float;
var slider2: float;
var Hour: float;
private
var Tod: float;

var sun: Light;

var speed = 50;

var NightFogColor: Color;
var DuskFogColor: Color;
var MorningFogColor: Color;
var MiddayFogColor: Color;

var NightAmbientLight: Color;
var DuskAmbientLight: Color;
var MorningAmbientLight: Color;
var MiddayAmbientLight: Color;

var NightTint: Color;
var DuskTint: Color;
var MorningTint: Color;
var MiddayTint: Color;

var SkyBoxMaterial1: Material;
var SkyBoxMaterial2: Material;

var SunNight: Color;
var SunDay: Color;

//THIS WAS ADDED IN TUTORIAL NUMBER 24. It allows for changing the color that reflects of a water object.
//Uncheck IncludeWater if you are not interested in using this.
var Water: GameObject;
var IncludeWater = false;
var WaterNight: Color;
var WaterDay: Color;


function OnGUI() {

    if (slider >= 1.0) {
        slider = 0;
    }

    slider = GUI.HorizontalSlider(Rect(20, 20, 200, 30), slider, 0, 1.0);
    Hour = slider * 24;
    Tod = slider2 * 24;
    sun.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3((slider * 360) - 90, 0, 0);
    slider = slider + Time.deltaTime / speed;
    sun.color = Color.Lerp(SunNight, SunDay, slider * 2);

    //THIS WAS ADDED IN TUTORIAL NUMBER 24. It allows for changing the color that reflects of a water object.
    //Uncheck IncludeWater if you are not interested in using this.
    if (IncludeWater == true) {
        Water.renderer.material.SetColor("_horizonColor", Color.Lerp(WaterNight, WaterDay, slider2 * 2 - 0.2));
    }

    if (slider < 0.5) {
        slider2 = slider;
    }
    if (slider > 0.5) {
        slider2 = (1 - slider);
    }
    sun.intensity = (slider2 - 0.2) * 1.7;


    if (Tod < 4) {
        //it is Night
        RenderSettings.skybox = SkyBoxMaterial1;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
        SkyBoxMaterial1.SetColor("_Tint", NightTint);
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = NightAmbientLight;
        RenderSettings.fogColor = NightFogColor;
    }
    if (Tod > 4 && Tod < 6) {
        RenderSettings.skybox = SkyBoxMaterial1;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", (Tod / 2) - 2);
        SkyBoxMaterial1.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(NightTint, DuskTint, (Tod / 2) - 2));
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp(NightAmbientLight, DuskAmbientLight, (Tod / 2) - 2);
        RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp(NightFogColor, DuskFogColor, (Tod / 2) - 2);
        //it is Dusk

    }
    if (Tod > 6 && Tod < 8) {
        RenderSettings.skybox = SkyBoxMaterial2;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", (Tod / 2) - 3);
        SkyBoxMaterial2.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(DuskTint, MorningTint, (Tod / 2) - 3));
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp(DuskAmbientLight, MorningAmbientLight, (Tod / 2) - 3);
        RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp(DuskFogColor, MorningFogColor, (Tod / 2) - 3);
        //it is Morning

    }
    if (Tod > 8 && Tod < 10) {
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = MiddayAmbientLight;
        RenderSettings.skybox = SkyBoxMaterial2;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 1);
        SkyBoxMaterial2.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(MorningTint, MiddayTint, (Tod / 2) - 4));
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp(MorningAmbientLight, MiddayAmbientLight, (Tod / 2) - 4);
        RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp(MorningFogColor, MiddayFogColor, (Tod / 2) - 4);

        //it is getting Midday

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the flashlight in the code? You can probably just enable = false

Comment: This question cannot be answered with only the information given. Flashlights are not built into Unity3d, only various ways to implement and manage them.

Answer (score 0):

if the Light you need to turn of at a certain time is a separate gameObject you could do something like this

```
public  var Light : GameObject; // Then link it in , in the editor
```

then you add

```
 Light.SetActive(true); // or false
```

to one of your conditionals (if statements) in your desired time gap, another way to enable and disable something is to add .enabled = false; // or true, as a callback to the Light Object